# Pandas: Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am attempting to find the best method for matrix multiplication using pandas.  Suppose I want to do a simple exercise: xyx' ...[1x5][5x5][5x1]'.

```
in:

ydates = pd.date_range('20170101',periods=5)
y = pd.DataFrame(np.identity(5),index=['f','o','b','a','r'],columns=['f','o','b','a','r'])
xdata = list(range(1,6))
x = pd.DataFrame(xdata,index=['f','o','b','a','r'])
x.loc['o'] = np.nan
mm = x.T.dot(y)*x.T  



out: 

        f   o   b   a   r
    0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I would expect to get:

```
     0
f  1.0
o  NaN
b  3.0
a  4.0
r  5.0
```

My questions are:

1) How do I align these? Is there a better way than doing the double transpose?

2) Is there a way to account for nans?

2) Is there a more efficient way to do matrix algebra using python/pandas?

Comment: There is a `nan` in your first vector, that at some point gets multiplied in the matrix product, making the entire result `nan`. .. the behavior you are expecting is that it return `nan * something` gives you 0?

Comment: Also, your last operation isn't matrix multiplication, but elementwise multiplication... it would seem you want `x.T.dot(y).dot(x)`. So I'm not sure you why you are expecting that, but a 1X5*5X1 matrix multiplication gives you a 1X1 "matrix"

Comment: Yes, the nan is intentional . I don't want a 1x1, but a 1x5 which would account for the nan as shown in the example.  I've edited the original prompt to make that more clear.

Comment: Expecting that operation not to produce more NaNs is roughly like expecting infinity - infinity to be 0. Properties like "multiplying a matrix by an identity matrix leaves it unchanged" depend on real-number axioms that don't hold for infinities or NaN.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy`has several functions that handle matrix products - `np.dot`, `np.einsum` and `np.matmul` (and the `@` operator).  `*` is defined as element wise multiplication (except for `np.matrix` class).  All are optimized for speed.  But they also propagate `nan`.

Using numpy arrays instead of pandas:

```
In [314]: y = np.eye(5)
In [316]: y
Out[316]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

To do transpose on `x` we need to make it 2d; and to assign `nan` it has to be float.

```
In [320]: x = np.arange(1,6).astype(float).reshape(1,5)
In [321]: x[0,1]=np.nan
In [322]: x
Out[322]: array([[  1.,  nan,   3.,   4.,   5.]])
In [323]: x.T       # column vector
Out[323]: 
array([[  1.],
       [ nan],
       [  3.],
       [  4.],
       [  5.]])
In [324]: np.dot(y, x.T)
Out[324]: 
array([[ nan],
       [ nan],
       [ nan],
       [ nan],
       [ nan]])
```

Why this `dot` result?  It multiplies each row of `y` by the column of `x.T`, and sums the values.  Because of the `nan` one of those products for each row of `y` is `1*nan` or `0*nan`; any product or sum involving `nan` produces `nan`, to the result is all `nan`.

I suspect you were hoping that `0*nan == 0`.  Like:

```
In [329]: x[0,1]=100
In [330]: np.dot(y, x.T)
Out[330]: 
array([[   1.],
       [ 100.],
       [   3.],
       [   4.],
       [   5.]])
```

There are some `numpy` functions that skip `nan`. `np.dot` isn't one of them.

```
In [333]: x[0,1]=np.nan
In [336]: y*x
Out[336]: 
array([[  1.,  nan,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  nan,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  nan,   3.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  nan,   0.,   4.,   0.],
       [  0.,  nan,   0.,   0.,   5.]])
In [339]: np.nansum(y*x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[339]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
```

This sort of works.  It skipped the `nan` when summing across rows; but the 2nd value is 0, not `nan`.

---

The `np.nan...` functions work by temporarily replacing the `nan` with something innocuous like 0 or 1.  I could do that in your case with:

```
In [369]: x
Out[369]: array([[  1.,  nan,   3.,   4.,   5.]])
In [370]: x1, mask = np.lib.nanfunctions._replace_nan(x.T,1)
In [371]: x1
Out[371]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
In [372]: mask
Out[372]: 
array([[False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
In [373]: x2 = np.dot(y, x1)
In [374]: x2[mask] = np.nan
In [375]: x2
Out[375]: 
array([[  1.],
       [ nan],
       [  3.],
       [  4.],
       [  5.]])
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I DO want to retain the nan, which is why I included it in the example.  Is there another way to do matrix alegbra, aside from np.dot, that does retain nans?

Comment: You can use a mask to set the desired element to `np.nan`. See my edits.  One way or other `nan` has to treated as a special case.   Otherwise it propagates:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN